# php mvc router dispatcher and authentication

Tags: php, authentication, model-view-controller, router, dispatcher

I am working on code someone wrote based on Fat-Free Framework. Basically its a CRM.
I have seen that he uses a dispatch function like the one i here:
[What is the difference between URL Router and Dispatcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700603/what-is-the-difference-between-url-router-and-dispatcher)
I have not found enough documentation on this approach.
Anyway he also put the authentication in the dispatcher like this:

```
function dispatch()
{
    if(UserManager::isLogin())
    {
        $controller = $router->getController();
        $actionName = $router->getAction();
        $controller[$actionName]();
    }
    else
    {
        routeTo('/login');
    }
}
```

My question is: Do you think it is correct to put one centralized authentication check inside the dispatcher for all the controllers or would you do a log in check inside each controller, or would you do something else? I appropriate examples from well known framework or CMS.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First F3 does not allow dispatching by default so the approach is to use the beforeroute() function.
In your base controller(or class routed to) add

```
public function beforeroute($f3){
   if(!UserManager::isLogin())
   {
       $f3->reroute('/login');
   }
}
```

Then any time you call the class (which extends your base class with the above function), it first validates the login. Hope this helps.